# Do operators acting on the Hilbert space of a quantum state form a Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics

I am taking a class on quantum mechanics and the following is stated: The space $\mathcal{F}$ of wavefunctions we will consider is a subspace of $L^2$ with good regularity properties (e.g. Schwartz space). The space is equipped with the standard scalar product $\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle$. We will also consider operators acting on those wavefunctions, and associated to those operators is a commutator. Namely, if $A$, $B$ are two operators, then $[A,B]=AB-BA$.

My question is: This commutator looks a lot like a Lie bracket. Is it one? If so, is the space of operators a Lie algebra, and can we use Lie algebra techniques to study it? One idea that immediately comes to mind is to use representation theory to study those operators. I'm a mathematics student so I have little background in physics, sorry if this question sounds naive or obvious. In turn, physical intuition is probably lost on me as well.

Comment: Yes. You are correct on all counts. The important implications of this are still lost on me, but there is somehow an association between generators of symmetries and observables. Lie stuff enters in at the level of generators of symmetries (the lie algebra associated to a lie group of symmetries). Observables are just Hermitian operators. Again, why generators of symmetries and observables should have anything to do with each other is a mystery to me, but I think that's why Lie theory is so relevant in QM.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this reinforces my intuition that there is something deeper  going on. Hopefully someone else can weigh in on this and explain further.

Comment: A more concrete comment (that someone else should fill in the details of, because I haven't yet figured out the best way to explain it): The Lie algebra of a subgroup of the group of invertible operators on a vector space will be a Lie subalgebra of the set of linear operators on the same vector space, where the Lie bracket is given by the commutator. This is a classical result and you can find many pdfs that step through the derivation. So you're exactly right that the commutator is important because it is a Lie bracket for the Lie algebra of some important Lie group.

Comment: You can find a pdf of Peter Woit's book *Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations: An Introduction* at [his Columbia.edu web page](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/QMbook/). I would recommend reading specifically sections 1.4-1.5, it's only a couple pages and atleast partially addresses your question; the book as a whole provides a good approach to this general concept.

Comment: Note that if you have *any*  associative algebra, then with the commutator $[x,y] := xy-yx$ it will be a Lie algebra.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins: it's not that there is a relation between all observables and the generators of symmetries. But in the physical applications, there is usually one central observable and that is the Hamiltonian H. This observable represents the energy of the system. All the generators that commute with this H will be generators of symmetries of H. For instance, the H of the hydrogen atom commutes with all generators of rotational symmetries. As a consequence, the representation theory of the rotations gives you the eigenstates of H almost for free.

Comment: @Raskolnikov right, but there's still an interesting theoretical question as to why generators of symmetries and observables should be the same kind of mathematical object. In fact, perhaps more interestingly, they aren't exactly the same kind of thing. Generators of symmetries are anti-Hermitian, and observables are Hermitian.